# Limit the number of threads numpy 1.19.2 uses

Tags: python, numpy, pthreads

## Context

My computer mysteriously shutsdown when all my cores go to 100% in `htop`.

I am running a simple program using `sklearn.impute.KNNImputer` from `scikit-learn`

I have read that I need to limit the number of threads that `numpy` uses because `scikit-learn` depends on `numpy`.

## Question

> How do I limit the number of threads `numpy` uses?

## Things I have tried:

I tried the following in my python script (see bottom of question)

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1" # export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
```

## information

My `numpy` version is 1.19.2

running `np.__config__.show()` returns

```
blas_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs =['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/include']

blas_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/include']

lapack_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/lib']
 define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/include']

lapack_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/conor/anaconda3/envs/py383/include']
```

here is a tiny program to run while looking at `htop`

```
# knn imputation transform for the horse colic dataset
from numpy import isnan
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
# load dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/horse-colic.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None, na_values='?')
X = dataframe.values
# define imputer
imputer = KNNImputer()
# fit on the dataset
imputer.fit(X)
# transform the dataset
Xtrans = imputer.transform(X)
```

Comment: What about the [`threadpoolctl`](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl) library? The `threadpool_limits` contextmanager seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(1)
```

successfully restricts `numpy` 1.19.2 on `Ubuntu 18.04` to one cpu